# How to create large sized files that have unique content in Windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems

I need to create a large sized file that doesn't have repeated stuff in it so that even on zipping, I don't get the size reduced.

Comment: If you're still around, i suggest you check my answer. I believe it's the strongest answer. The one you marked as Answer fails to fulfill your requirement. https://superuser.com/a/1658098/112542

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to create random dump files is by using 'fsutil' in your command prompt.

> C:\>fsutil file createnew another1.txt 32234567000
>
> File C:\another1.txt is created

This creates 32GB file instantly which has random content.

Comment: created instantly. that too such big file. :)

Comment: There’s no way to create a file “instantly” with random content. If you mean, “indeterminate” then that is a different story. But, it is far from random. Instead, it just contains bits and bytes of old data left on the drive. That’s not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong by using the word random. It creates a file of useless data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure doing this and zipping it up will allow it to compress a decent amount (which is not what OP wants as stated in question).

Comment: It may be even worse. [This site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-file) says about `createnew`: "Creates a file of the specified name and size, with content that consists of zeroes".

Comment: On my PC this command creates a file where all bytes are 0. Even on my hard disk with the file size set to 1TB I still get only 0s.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski  that does appear to be the case, which is, of course, impossible to do “instantly.” On another note, how is this the answer? The question was to create a file with random content.

Comment: @Appleoddity I imagine it could be done instantly with some tricks like sparseness or lazy init etc. It doesn't matter though, there is no randomness at all; for this reason I have downvoted this answer and upvoted the `dd` one.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The file created doesn't contain random content. The file contains all spaces, ASCII character 32. Not random, not unique. A file i created with fsutil contain only this character, repeated many times: `" "`

Comment: Since the file contains all spaces, on compression to zip, the compressed file will be much, much smaller. So if you're trying to test a process which inherently compresses the file (such as embedding it as an object in an Excel spreadsheet), you're not getting the test you think you're getting.

Comment: That does not create a file with "random content", but with zeros.

Answer (score 8):

On Windows, you can create a file containing truly unique content with Powershell. No third-party software needed. No admin rights needed.

As opposed to fsutil, the output will not contain 0's or spaces. Each time you run the command, the output will be unique. On compression, the file will retain it's original size.

The output will look something like this:

> 䫲藌㦖鐆쩘ꌓ⮅픻씙방醒ম擾酰₵廙⊌弓똌硣浍鐟ઘ⃭佐怱쎜鼋ꄻ윤訟ᦟ맂㱆�㔭ර槗旌閣㏏⯉來殰鲑奣鑍翴㑈Ꮪ嚠昲︇퇇뻕耣珁犒晥䒋酉懒䊿䱵漝벻玓⃸啈�펕戶臓헬珎宇ꄌꖓ萿 etc....

**The command**

```
$out = new-object byte[] 100000; (new-object Random).NextBytes($out); [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('C:\100K.txt', $out)
```

Replace `100000` with whatever size you want, in bytes. You can use an [online converter](https://whatsabyte.com/P1/byteconverter.htm) if you need help defining the size you prefer.

Replace `C:\100K.txt` with the filepath you want. If you provide a name without a path, it will be saved in your Windows profile folder (or maybe C:, depending on your system configuration). The file extension has no impact on the process.

**Breakdown**

This is a series of three commands. The first command creates an empty array called $out, of the size you specify. The second command loads the array with random characters. The third command saves the array to a file.

Here's the [Microsoft support file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-7.1) for `new-object`.

This appears to be supported at least as far back as [Powershell 3.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-3.0). (Currently at version 7.x as of this writing).

Taken from:
https://www.digitalcitizen.life/3-ways-create-random-dummy-files-windows-given-size

**Limit**

I can output files up to 2G. Anything larger hits a limit. For example, 3G gives:

> "Cannot convert value "3000000000" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.""

[This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/66111182/209942) shows a way to write large files in chunks. Basically, wrap a do..while around the commands which load the array and write to file. The writes need to append to the file.

Regardless of limits on array-size, I think you'll want to consider your available RAM.

Comment: Doesn't work for large sizes as bytes exceed Int32

Comment: @NedMartin How large? I created 100 MB files no problem with this method.

Comment: I was trying to create 2GB and 4GB files.

Comment: @NedMartin i created a 2G file no problem. It breaks at 3G with `"new-object : Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "3000000000", for "Byte[]" to type "System.Int32": Cannot convert value "3000000000" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."`

Comment: @NedMartin I believe this is a limit on the array-size. In my code, the array is `$out`. This answer shows a possible way to write the file in chunks https://stackoverflow.com/a/66111182/209942 But i bet that code could be much simplified, so we could still achieve a relatively shorter, one-line command. Also, he recommends 4K chunks, but so tiny! I would do 1G chunks, since my command can do that.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked. I have used the value of 1073741824 to create a 1GB file with pseudorandom data.

Answer (score 7):

Under Linux the easiest way to do this would be the dd command. There is a Windows version at http://www.chrysocome.net/dd

To create a random file with a size of 1GB you can run the command

`dd if=/dev/random of=random.file bs=1M count=1000`

This means: use a blocksize of 1 MB and read/write 1000 blocks.

btw. on Linux you should use `/dev/urandom` but for this Windows version it has to be `/dev/random`

Comment: The question is for Windows, not Linux.

Comment: That is possible using Cygwin on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Install Veracrypt.

Create an encrypted container that is formatted (not quick format) with whatever size you want.

This will ensure the contents are cryptographically random.

Alternatively, create a file with `fsutil` [as suggested by fossa](https://superuser.com/a/1322158/860739) then encrypt the contents with a one-time pad (for example, with AES using a random passphrase that you throw away).

Comment: Requires extra software, instead of using built-in Windows utilities. fsutil doesn't produce a file containing unique content. As a result, on compression it will become very tiny (even with Windows Explorer encryption).