# Generate a large file with a single or repeating characters Windows command line, batch, or powershell?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Is there a way to generate a large file (like 1GB or larger) with just a repeating single character, preferably Windows command line, but powershell will do too.

I know I can use

```
fsutil file createnew test.txt 1073741824
```

But this creates an empty file. I'd like for it to be a repeating single character like all `1`'s  or repeating characters like `012345678901234567890` (not random) ...

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Have you seen this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1658098/855367)?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio - Thanks, yes I have. But that generates random data. I want a single character or repeating pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following PowerShell command in a Command Prompt (CMD):

```
powershell -command "'1234567890'*107374183" > file.txt
```

This will duplicate the string "1234567890" for 107374183 times,
creating a file of size 1073741830 bytes.

Comment: Thanks. Gives me an out of memory exception error. I'll look to see if I can find a way to increase it.

Comment: PowerShell has a problem here with such a large number. I divided by 10 and it worked. You may need to create 10 such files, then combine them with the [cp command](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) with something like `cp file1.txt+file2.txt+..+file10.txt target.txt` or `cp file*.txt target.txt`.

Comment: No matter what I do it won't make the file bigger than 204MB. Even if I do a `Get-Content file*.txt | Set-Content BigFile.txt`. Even set `maxmemorypercellmb` to 2GB (2147483647).

Comment: A dumb DOS utility such as `cp` might do better.

Answer (score 1):

In your command line:

```bath
(@echo\1>>File.txt & @for /L %L in (1 1 28)do @copy/y /b .\File.txt .\TMP.txt >nul && @copy/y /b .\File.txt + .\TMP.txt .\File.txt >nul) && del .\tmp.txt
```

In your bat/cmd file:

```bath
@echo off && cd /d "drive:\path\to\file_create"

echo\1>>.\File.txt 

for /L %%L in (1 1 28)do >nul (
    copy/y /b .\File.txt .\TMP.txt
    copy/y /b .\File.txt + .\TMP.txt .\File.txt 
   )

del /q /f /a .\TMP.txt
```

- Your new file File.txt and size 1.00 GB (1,073,741,824 bytes)

[image]